# How many -digit integers have the property that the block of its first  digits is a prime or divisible by  for all 1 ≤  ≤ ?

Tags: mathematics

Are there infinitely many integers with the property that the block of its first  digits (for all , 1 ≤  ≤ , where  is the number of its digits) is either a prime number or is divisible by ?

An example of such a number with nine digits is 149,251,283.

If not, what is the largest number with this property?

Comment: I initially parsed the sentence as "divisible by (k or a prime)" and was confused for a while.

Comment: Also, it doesn't look so meaningful to try solving this by hand, and it looks straightforward to solve it by programming, so I don't see much puzzling value. (Compare it to the ant walk problem where hand optimization is feasible to some extent and programming is not that straightforward IMHO.)

Comment: This is a good question for the math SE but not really for puzzling. I also strongly suspect there are only finitely many such integers. Given such a number all its blocks of first $k$ digits are also of this type. This means if you know all such $n$ digits numbers you can find the $n+1$ digit ones by trying to extend the $n$ digits ones by one digit.

Comment: @Bubbler:  It's straightforward to solve by programming if there is in fact a largest number with that property.

Comment: If the possibility of blocks being prime is excluded them there is indeed a largest such number. See puzzle 32 in https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/53116137-the-bogot-puzzles. Likewise if they must all be primes.

Comment: I do believe there is a largest number, since the probability of a length-k number being a multiple of k or being a prime converges to zero.

Comment: Just primes: http://oeis.org/A024770.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I commented already, I have a heuristic argument that

> there is some largest number that satisfies the condition

because

> for a length-k number, both the probability of being a multiple of k and being prime converges to zero as k increases.

Based on this belief, I quickly coded a program in Factor:

```
: good-number? ( k n -- ? )
  [ swap mod 0 = ] [ nip prime? ] 2bi or ;

: next-numbers ( k seq -- k+1 seq' )
  [ 1 + ] [ [ 10 * 10 <iota> [ + ] with map ] map concat ] bi*
  [ drop ] [ [ good-number? ] with filter ] 2bi ;

1 9 [1,b] [ next-numbers [ f ] when-empty ] follow
```

It took a few minutes to run in the GUI interpreter.

It internally uses Miller-Rabin probabilistic primality test, but two runs gave equal results, so I think the output is correct.

The number of n-digit numbers for each n was as follows:

> ```
>  n          1     2     3     4     5      6      7      8      9     10
>  count      9    66   320  1063  3141   7708  14885  25994  41508  57500
>
>  n         11    12    13    14    15     16     17     18     19     20
>  count  74514 87867 92237 97764 87821  74203  60737  47573  34498  20443
>
>  n         21    22    23    24    25     26     27     28     29     30
>  count  13593  7599  4775  2557  1524    821    468    212     94     35
>
>  n         31    32    33    34    35
>  count     18    10     7     2     0
> ```

and the largest number was:

> **5011561981801201672032001313475247**, a 34-digit number. The other 34-digit number was 1860544080133200006094325972409613.